# What steps must an employer take to keep health information confidential?

Tags: canada, health, privacy, law, confidentiality

What steps must an employer take to keep health information confidential?
This question is mainly legal but for a few reason I thought this site would be better than law.stackexchange.com
Where I work we need to get COVID tested regularly. I think they often hire different labs to do it. Sometimes they have surveys for us to fill out, with information like our gender, allergies, health care number and birthdate. I noticed last time the survey was done through Google Docs/Google forms.
My first question is, is this secure enough? Do they have an obligation to secure the data? I had expected workers in the healthcare field not to store patient information in Google.

When I was in line to check in for the test, the receptionist was behind a thick piece of plastic. She told us we had to shout so that she could hear her. I wasn't really comfortable shouting personal information like my name (ok this isn't personal), birthday, health care number etc. There were lots of people in line and everyone could hear when someone shouted.

I found just showing her my cards with the information written on it solved the problem. Is this an acceptable solution? From a legal standpoint, are they required to take steps to keep personal/medical information confidential? After the receptionist wrote down my information she asked if she could take a picture of the form she just filled out. Why would she ask me?

I know I'm a bit paranoid about these things. I used to work at a fortune 500 company with such a culture. The company was extremely proactive about preventing themselves from getting sued, so it was very frowned upon whenever someone discussed personal or health care information (even voluntarily). I'm curious why this may be? I guess it's because they could argue they are being terminated because of a protected class?

Comment: Generally speaking questions of "is it legal" and "do they have an obligation to..." are going to be off topic here as the answer is "it depends" and "get proper legal advice", check out the [tour]. I think your original idea of /law will have a better chance of getting a helpful answer, here I VTC as asking for legal advice. Though it can possibly be salvaged if you can identify actual problem you are facing, and how to solve it in the workplace (besides the shouting one, as this you've clearly figured out already).

Comment: You are certainly not paranoid!

Comment: Welcome new user.  Great question. But please note, at the end of your typing, you add some new incidental questions.  I would urge you to just click edit and delete that.  There's pretty strictly **one question per question** on these sites. Please don't hesitate to ask those other questions separately as new questions.  The edit button  is below your writing to the left.

Comment: @Fattie thanks for the welcome. By itself could "why are some corporate cultural adverse to discussing health information?" stand as a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> She told us we had to shout so that she could hear her.

When that happens, I say this:

> Patients can not shout private information. Please get your supervisor. Thanks.

A lot of problems in life are caused by being an "enabler", so to speak!

1. If someone asks you to **do something absurd**
2. **Don't** do it

> I know I'm a bit paranoid about these things.

Not in the slightest. On the contratry: you should question "why you ever thought you may be wrong."

**You were one billion percent correct.**

The person who suggested you *yell private health information* is a complete idiot, but more significantly the supervisor of that facility should be fired and sued.

You were one billion percent correct.

Answer (score 1):

> What steps must an employer take to keep health information confidential?

If you are inquiring about legal requirements then https://law.stackexchange.com/questions would indeed be a better place. You would also have to add a country & state & location tag since rules varies wildly from place to place even at the local level.

In addition most companies have their own set of regulations which are typically published in the employee hand book or on the HR website etc. Your first step should be read up on this.

Once you know what the regulations are you compare them to what's actually happening. If everything is done according to the rules, you have no reason to complain but instead you need to work with HR on changing the rules, if you don't like it. That's going to be an uphill battle.

If current practices are NOT in compliance with your local rules or the rules simply don't cover them you can talk to HR and ask for clarification. It's perfectly ok to make constructive suggestion on how to amend the rules to cover the current Covid situation better.